# Culture of Pokemon WiFi battling extremely competitive in X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

My question has to deal the general culture of wifi battles in Pokemon X/Y.  I just finished the Elite 4 and am now looking for something to do.  WiFi battling looks fun, but spending hours upon hours breeding the perfect monsters is very unattractive to me. Would I see even mild success if I brought my story team online to battle random opponents?  Or do you have to have a perfect Smogon-rules team to stand a chance?

I'm hoping I can just wifi battle casually and if I really like it, I will spend time breeding and building a competitive team.

Comment: Its all fairly casual, I've faced people running fully setup teams, as well as people who run 6 birds for some reason. In other words: you'll be fine. Use Smogon as a guide, not a bible. Having said that do note that Single player is geared toward you winning, so you may find that strategy plays a bigger part in multi

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.  It seems everyone talking about wifi battling online won't even consider using anything that doesn't have perfect IV/EV and such. I think it would be fun to create and train up an ok competitive team with a sweeper, a tank, and stuff but I can't be bothered to make sure their stats are perfect.

Comment: I wouldn't say perfect IVs are necessary beyond high-level competitive play, but EVs are fairly simple to train up. *Generally* speaking, use the super training to max out either Atk or Sp.Atk (depends on which your pokemon uses), and divide the rest as you see fit (speed and HP are usually good candidates for the rest). It may get more complicated than that the further down the competitive rabbit hole you go, but that seems to be the basics; Max out your (sp)atack to hit hard, and then either put into speed to hit hard first, or HP to better soak up a hit.

Answer (score 5):

I have some experience in three areas of WiFi battles;

### Battle Spot - Rating Battle

This is where the lion's share of the competitive teams are. You may get lucky at first, as the system seems to attempt to match you against someone *near* your rating. And if your team (casual or not) has a decent move-set, type distribution, and are EV trained - you should stand a fairly decent chance.

Advance your rating too far, however, and you will start to get into the more competitive teams. At this point you may be cursing your earlier good luck at being paired against teams you could beat, as the competitive teams start moping the floor with your pokemon.

### Battle Spot - Free Battle

Free battles are more of a mixed bag. On the one hand, *most* trainers attempting to show off their skills and earn bragging rights will be in the rated battles. On the other, free battles aren't as restrictive and allow all sorts of legendaries and load-outs that may otherwise be restricted. So while sometimes you might go against some trainer with 6 Magikarp, other times you're up against all three Kalos legendaries, a Mega Mewtwo, and other dirty tricks. Granted, having all those legendaries doesn't by any stretch of the imagination make them invulnerable (personally, I find that most trainers who overload their team with legendaries seem to overlook the fact that they still need good move-sets and strategy), they often do have higher stats and hard-to-deal-with moves.

Like I said, a mixed bag. Enjoy the battles for what they are and have a thick skin. Sometimes you'll wipe the floor with them, sometimes they'll hammer you into the ground. But other times you'll get just the right mix and have a suspenceful battle that could go either way.

For what it's worth, my field team, whose held items are largely comprised of things like Amulet coins, and includes things like a male Combee, A HM slave Diggersby, and a Smeargle whose only offensive attack is False Swipe - This field team has a ~50% win rate in free battles (if you include the opponent's rage disconnect as a win - I know I do).

### Player Search System (PSS) Battle Challenges

Challenge a random passerby to a battle. This is another mixed bag of a different sort. While you could roughly tell the expected difference between free and rating battles, You don't really know what to expect from passersby. If they accept your challenge, do they have a competitive team in the wings? Do they have a terrible team, but are bored? Somewhere in the middle?

Typically though, those who have challenged me from their passersby list, with the exception of one, have all been curb-stomped by my semi-competitive team.

I have only had one person battle me repeatedly enough that I added him to my 'friend list' (I later removed his friend code from my 3DS) and battled him again with the game chat enabled. So I can't really comment on if there's a lot of 'smack talk' or anything that goes on. My one and only voice-chat enabled battle was with a French kid who didn't say a whole lot.

Comment: Alright cool!  Thank you so much for your detailed response! Tons of great info.  Guess I'll hit up the Free battles and see what comes up! I've also found communities dedicated to casual wifi battling such as www.reddit.com/r/CasualPokemonBattles so I can find people there to play with too! Thanks again! I wish I could +1 your answer; alas I have only one rep, haha.

Comment: @Jeph - you can mark it as accepted, by clicking the check mark under the vote count (it awards Trent with +15 rep, and +2 to yourself as well :))

Comment: Fun fact: I was facing a team of Mewtwo, Zygarde, Xerneas and Zapdos (try saying that five times fast!) in a Rotation Battle. I defeated the entire team without using any attacking moves, only Status. Fun!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Some random passerby kept challenging me to a battle. I finally caved, found out he had Blaziken, Yvetal, Mewtwo, Garchomp, Talonflame and something I can't remember. Anyway... It's probably better you just watch :P. R79G-WWWW-WWW3-F3KT. When it ends, it's him rage quitting.

Comment: You should've seen what happened when my friend threw out his armload of legendaries and i only had one on my team. Ended up with me winning by my Torterra downing Ho-oh under sunlight activated by a Groudon